# Uncertainty calculation for mean of spatially gridded data

Tags: uncertainty, error-propagation

I have data on a spatial grid. For each cell of the grid there is a best estimate ($x_i$) and an uncertainty ($\sigma_i$) which is specific to that grid cell. I'd like to calculate the mean for the whole area and the uncertainty on that mean. What is the correct way to do this? I have considered the following two options, but perhaps neither are correct.

*Option 1:* Standard deviation of the mean: $\sigma_\bar{x} = \sigma_x / \sqrt{N}$ where $N$ is the sample size, $\sigma_x$ is the uncertainty of each measurement. The problem here is that each of my measurements have different uncertainties associated with them.

*Option 2:* Just propagate the uncertainty using the equation for the mean. If $\bar{x} = \frac{\sum{x_i}}{N}$ then following standard rules for error propagation for summing a bunch of values and dividing by a constant, this gives $\sigma_\bar{x} = \frac{\sqrt{\sum{\sigma_i^2}}}{N}$ (I think). This just doesn't seem right for some reason - mainly I can't find anything online to confirm this, when it should be fairly common scenario to encounter.

For context (in case it is important), the data we're talking about are surface temperature measurements of the Earth's surface measured from space.

Comment: Missing from this is any description of spatial *correlation,* which for temperature one would expect to be high.  How are you modeling this correlation?

Comment: I'm not modelling this correlation. I wouldn't even know where to start doing that, though any suggestions are welcome. Is this why the 'naive' approach of propagating the errors through the equation for the mean wouldn't work?

Comment: To the extent there is positive spatial correlation, the naive approach grossly underestimates the standard error of the mean.